# javascript not showing message

Tags: javascript, php

I have question about below code:

```html
$(document)
.on("submit", "#board_login", function(){
  if(validate("login")){
  $.post('/ajax_login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
   if(data === 0){
    alert("Username or Password is incorrect");
   } else if (data == 1){
    window.open('index.php', '_self'); 
   }
  });
 }
})
;

function validate(){
  if($("#b_username").val() === ''){
   alert("Missing login!");
   $("#b_username").focus();
   return false;
  }
  if($("#b_password").val() === ''){
   alert("Missing password!");
   $("#b_password").focus();
   return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It is showing only missing login or password, but never shows username or password is incorrect. I am able to log in, log out etc.

Comment: The obvious question, then is "when the username or password is incorrect, what is the value of `data` as returned from the `$.post()`?"

Comment: Your `validate()` function does not have any arguments, but you call it with "login" parameter.

Comment: @hamed That should not really matter. The function will run anyway. I actually don't understand what OP receives for `data`. I mean he assumes that if data is identical to `0` it will give the alert.

Comment: @yamciayamcia Why don't you console.log(data) to see what it returns when something is incorrect?

Comment: @Mikey can you tell me how? I am a newbie in PHP/JS... :)